# Why does the string having length C not have an impact on the overall system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

The Q:

[image]

Given:

a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub> are the accelerations of mass 8 kg , 2 kg respectively.

i) Total Length of Sting $L=4 x_{1}+2 x_{2}+C$

ii) $\frac{d L}{d t}=\frac{4 d\left(x_{1}\right)}{d t}+\frac{2 d\left(x_{2}\right)}{d t}+\frac{d c}{d t}$

- C is a Constant. CPorCdwill not change the answer.
  $\Rightarrow 4 v_{1} \rightarrow 4 a_{1}+2 v_{2} \rightarrow 2 a_{2}+0$

There is no friction between surfaces & the strings are massless.

**I am trying to find a constraint relation** between the acceleration of the 8kg & the 2kg masses. Below is my solution.

1. Total Length of String $L$
   $=4 x_{1}+2 x_{2}+C$
2. $\frac{d L}{d t}=\frac{4 d\left(x_{1}\right)}{d t}+\frac{2 d\left(x_{2}\right)}{d t}+\frac{d c}{d t}$

$\Rightarrow 4 v_{1} \rightarrow 4 a_{1}+2 v_{2} \rightarrow 2 a_{2}+0$

The solution has assumed C to be extra length of the string. If we either increase or decrease C, the answer to the relation will not change.

My Q is: Why is that? I think if the strings are massless, it won’t but if the strings have mass, then it will impact the system since it will be more weight.

Am I correct ?

Comment: Diagram unclear. There's a pulley floating in mid air with no attachment (second from top). Is it fixed like the top pulley?  Otherwise, probably because d/dt of a constant is zero, as you correctly have right at the beginning. With conservation of energy, forces are related by distance travel of pulleys. adding an extension length C terminating in a fixed location doesn't change travel length or speed

Comment: @PeteW Yes , that is fixed.

Comment: @PeteW Because of mass right ?

Comment: Ok... plz fix the diagram

Comment: Ask yourself what is the total work done by the 2kg & 8kg mass assume the original position of the 2kg mass is at the level of the horizontal platform the 8kg mass sits (does it involve the distance "C")?

Comment: The result of the differential equation puzzles me, what is "a" representing?

Comment: @r13 Acceleration

Comment: 4d(x1)/dt = 4a1? Why? Also, on the next step, 4v1 ---> 4a1 + 2v2 ---> 2a2, how? Is this a shorthand representation, or you think the direct addition of v and a is valid?

Comment: @r13 This is knows as pulley constraint relation , it is used to find relation between acc of system of different masses.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't think I'm the only exception. You shall clearly indicate in your question what is the equation represents and cite a reference if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two questions.

### first question

> Why If we either increase or decrease C , the answer to the relation will not change.?

The reason is that if you place fix the rope at any point along the red arrow  (between the current fixing point and the start of length $x_2$) in the image below, there will be absolutely no effect on the system. (you can also fix it even lower but then the maximum travel $x_2$ is limited)

[image]

if the mass goes up, it can never climb above x_2, so that part (C) is just hanging there.  (if the rope is deformable that is another matter).

### second question

> I think if the strings are massless, it won’t but if the strings have mass , then it will impact the system since it will be more weight.

Again the mass of that particular part (along C) is of no effect in the system, because that part of the rope never changes its kinetic state. On  the other hand, the mass of rest of the rope would have had an effect on the forces. The effect would be greater if the mass of the rope is comparable to the other masses in the system.

### constraint relation

The equation you wrote about the length of the rope is correct:

$$L =4 x_{1}+2 x_{2}+C$$

However when you integrate it, the length L does not change over time (nor does C change with time) so:

$$\frac{d L}{d t}=\frac{d\left(  4 x_{1}\right)}{d t}+\frac{ d\left(2x_{2}\right)}{d t}+\frac{d C}{d t}  \Rightarrow$$

$$0 =4 \frac{d\left(   x_{1}\right)}{d t}+2 \frac{ d\left(x_{2}\right)}{d t}+ 0   \Rightarrow$$

$$0 =4 v_{1} +2 v_{2}+ 0    \tag{eq:2}$$

So the constraint for the accelerations is

$$v_2 = - 2 v_{1} $$

Where:

- $v_1$ is the velocity for body 1 (positive when body is moving to the **left**)
- $v_2$ is the velocity for body 2 (positive when body is moving **downwards**)

if you integrate again eq.2 you will get

$$0 =4 \frac{d}{dt}v_{1} +2 \frac{d}{dt}v_{2}    \Rightarrow$$
$$0 =4 a_{1} +2 a_{2}   $$
So:
$$ a_{2}    =- 2 a_{1} +$$

Where:

Where:

- $a_1$ is the acceleration for body 1 (positive when body is accelerating to the **left**)
- $a_2$ is the acceleration for body 2 (positive when body is accelerating **downwards**)

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to read your diagram correctly but it seems to me that if $d_C$ is the differential change of C, then of course it is zero. The length of C could be 100 meters or 1 cm, as long as the string is not flexible, C does not play a role.

Mass of the string either, it doesn't involve C into the equation.

When we let the system start to move the 2kg wight will move the 8kg mass to the right, the tension on the right string containing C is 1km. And the change in c would not affect the system. You could assume the point C on the vertical spring as the end of the string.

Comment: What if mass was involved , would it affect ?

Comment: @S.M.T, I have already answered, NO, in the second sentence. imagine you hang 10 kg to the string at a point higher than C, it never comes to play. but if you add the same near to 2kg mass if the pully moves past that 10kg, it comes into play.

Comment: K. I’ll think over it & get back to you sir. Really sleepy rn. It’s very late here. Mind is not working that good. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Constraint Method for Pulley Problems**

**Assumptions:**

1. The string is taut and inextensible at each and every point of time.
2. The string is massless and hence the tension is uniform throughout.
3. Pulley is massless.

**Freebody Diagram -**

[image]

**Equations:**

$4t_1 = m_1a_1$, $a_1 = \dfrac{4t_1}{m_1}$ -----(1)

$2t_2 = m_2a_2$, $a_2 = \dfrac{2t_2}{m_2} = g$ -----(2)

Constraint, $x_1 - x_2 = 0$ ($x_1 = x_2$)

Integrate the equation twice w/r to "$t$"to get, $a_1 - a_2 = 0$ -----(3)

Now, using equations (1), (2) & (3), you can solve the unknowns, which I leave it to you to figure out.

https://byjus.com/jee/pulley-problems/

Note, check my equations for mistakes. But in general, this explains why the distance "C" is a "non-matter".